# How to navigate to a fragment if current fragment is unknown?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-jetpack

I have some non-optimal app architecture and need to navigate from one fragment to another but it's not clear what is the current destination and arriving.
The simple way is to use something like this:

```
if (findNavController().currentDestination?.id == R.id.fragmentA) 
    findNavController().navigate (R.id.action_fragmentA_to_fragmentB)
```

but how can I make a navigation path dynamically if I know only `fragmentB`'s name / id? Something like

```
fun navigate(arriveFragment) = 
    findNavController().navigate (R.id.action_$currentFragment_to_$arriveFragment)
```

Comment: https://medium.com/android-news/navigation-controller-an-android-storyboard-4dd7229ca821

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can navigate using the fragment id

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.fragmentB)
```

`navigate()` also accept navArguments and navOptions

```
val args = bundleOf(
    "key" to "value"
)
val options = navOptions {
    popUpTo(R.id.fragmentA)
}
findNavController.navigate(R.id.fragmentB, args, options)
```